# How can I join two collections from different databases in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, microservices, mongoose-schema

I have two collections **Post** (belongs to posts database) and **User** (belongs to account database). My requirements to do join on these two collection. But I am unable to reproduce my requirements.

I am expecting joins on two collections.

Comment: You should use [aggregations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/).

Comment: Aggregations work on same database

Comment: You have different data in different databases, Didn't see that coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. There is a requirement in the backlog of MongoDB (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935) though.

As of now the only option you have is to manually query the two different databases and merge the results together as needed. Nevertheless from my point of view it's a little bit odd to have different databases for related collections. Maybe you can also think about redesigning your database design, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your collcetions are closely related, they should preferably be in the same database, as mentioned by other answers.

However, if you are running your MongoDB through MongoDB Atlas, you would be able to achieve what you describe, using Federated Databases to [Query across multiple Atlas clusters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/overview/). Then you can run aggregation pipelines that joins the two.

I am currently using this to query across two atlas clusters (a data warehouse with cold data, and a database with live data).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

also you can try this by using ejs,express and mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFHvf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FROKR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have only one Database having **Post** and **User** collections and not two separate databases. If yes then you can use MongoDB lookup aggregation to get the joined data using a single query.

```
db.Post.aggregate( [
        {
 $lookup:
   {
     from: "User",
     localField: "post_user_id",
     foreignField: "user_id",
     as: "post_docs"
   }
  }
  ]);
```

Comment: Databases are different (In sql that support) but in mongodb I try to find a way to do.